# How to get unique ids of views

Tags: android, android-layout

For the below posted layout I am trying to traverse throught the entire layout and display the ids of each view in the layout.
I tried the below posted code with the method

```
vg.getId()
```

but it displays the same ids for the each view in the layout

would you please tell me how to get unique ids of each view in the layout

**output**:

```
ew_1 I/ActMain: vg.getId() :2131427422
07-02 14:48:25.383 32647-32647/com.example.alteenos.test_traversethroughaview_1 I/ActMain: vg.getId() :2131427422
07-02 14:48:25.383 32647-32647/com.example.alteenos.test_traversethroughaview_1 I/ActMain: vg.getId() :2131427422
07-02 14:48:25.383 32647-32647/com.example.alteenos.test_traversethroughaview_1 I/ActMain: vg.getId() :2131427422
```

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/actMain_mainContainer"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.altenos.test_traversethroughaview_1.ActMain">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actMain_btn_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/decision_postponed" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actMain_linlay_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/actMain_btn_yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/decision_accepted" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/actMain_btn_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/decision_rejected" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actMain_tv_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actMain_linlay_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
```

**code**:

```
private int countViews(ViewGroup vg) {
    int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "vg.getId() :" + vg.getId());

        //if (vg.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
            //childCount += countViews((ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(i));
        //}
    }
    return childCount;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are logging the ID of the `ViewGroup`, not the child.

Answer (score 1):

You should log at View not ViewGroup

```
   private int countViews(ViewGroup vg) {
    int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG,"vg.getId() :",vg.getChildAt(i).getId());
        //Log.i(TAG, "vg.getId() :" + vg.getId()); Not this one

        //if (vg.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
            //childCount += countViews((ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(i));
        //}
    }
    return childCount;
}
```